# Append HTML Block jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am currently trying to append a block of HTML to a class on my page however whenever I use the following code it seems to break my whole entire script without any errors in the console:

```
$('.colon1').append("<div id='new-model-slider' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>
<div class='item'><img src='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/7-SsangYong_Tivoli.jpg' alt='SsangYong Tivoli Red'></div>
<div class='item'><img src='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/12-SsangYong_Tivoli_seating.jpg' alt='Tivoli Seating'></div>
</div>");
```

I'm aware this is bad practice when it comes to adding HTML however I am unable to use AJAX for a specific reason.

Any idea why this JS might not be appending within my class?

Thanks

Comment: String cannot be splitted on multiple lines

Comment: It doesn't append to my page and I added a console.log script at the bottom to see if it worked after this script has ran and it did not.

Comment: What breaks?... Is that the actual code you are using?

Comment: In javascript you cannot break lines without concatenating them with a `+` or using \

Comment: You should also make sure that there is at least one element with the class "colon1". jQuery won't tell you if your selector is wrong

Comment: You can use ES6 Template strings, wrap the string in `(backtick)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In javascript you cannot break lines without concatenating them with a `+` or using `\`

So here a few examples on how you can do it:

```js
// Example 1
$('.colon1').append("<div id='new-model-slider' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>\
<div class='item'><img src='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/7-SsangYong_Tivoli.jpg' alt='SsangYong Tivoli Red'>\</div>\
<div class='item'><img src='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/12-SsangYong_Tivoli_seating.jpg' alt='Tivoli Seating'></div>\
</div>");

// Example 2
var string = "";
string += "<div id='new-model-slider' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>";
string += "<div class='item'>";
string += "<img src='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/7-SsangYong_Tivoli.jpg' alt='SsangYong Tivoli Red'></div>";
$('.colon1').append(string);

//Example 3
$('.colon1').append("<div id='new-model-slider' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'><div class='item'><img rc='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/7-SsangYong_Tivoli.jpg' alt='SsangYong Tivoli Red'></div><div class='item'><img src='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/12-SsangYong_Tivoli_seating.jpg' alt='Tivoli Seating'></div></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colon1"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do the following

```
var appendstring = "";

appendstring+="<div id='new-model-slider' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>";
appendstring+="<div class='item'>";
appendstring+="<img src='/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/7-SsangYong_Tivoli.jpg' alt='SsangYong Tivoli Red'></div>";

//and so on ... for the rest of the string ( line by line )

$('.colon1').append(appendstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the below, removing the line breaks and using single quotes to quote your string of html (because that's more natural IMHO):

```
$('.colon1').append('<div id="new-model-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"><div class="item"><img src="media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/7-SsangYong_Tivoli.jpg"  alt="SsangYong Tivoli Red"></div><div class="item"><img src=""/media/wysiwyg/porto/cmspages/ssangyong/tivoli/12-SsangYong_Tivoli_seating.jpg"  alt="Tivoli Seating"></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split string on multiple lines, examples below:

```
var multiStr = "This is the first line" + 
"This is the second line" + 
"This is more...";
```

OR

```
var multiStr = "This is the first line \
This is the second line \
This is more...";
```

This info will help you to understand.
https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings